# Replace All string with Regex in the replacement string?

Tags: java, regex

Here is the text

```
<some string here could contain W or L letter><W1>123<W2>123<W3>123.
```

I hope to replace

```
<W(number)>
```

pattern to

```
<L(number)>
```

pattern.

```
String str = "<WLWLWL><W1><FS>123<W2><FS>345<E>";
    System.out.println(str);

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<[A-Z]\\d>");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }

    str.replaceAll("<[A-Z]\\d>", "<L\\d>");
    System.out.println(str);
```

I can find exactly what I want with code above but the replace is not working.

I suppose the replace string doesn't take the regex in it. So what's the best way to do it?

Comment: What is not working with your replace? Does it throw an error? (If yes, please [edit] the question and add the stacktrace.) Does it produce some unexpected result? (If yes, please [edit] the question and add your expected and actual output). It it something else? [edit] the question and don't make me guess what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative you can try is to use regex look around.

```
str = str.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z](?=\\d)", "L");
```

**RegEx explanation:**

```
[a-zA-Z](?=\\d)    finds the letter within (a-zA-Z) which has a number after it
```

**Output:**

```
<WLWLWL><L1><FS>123<L2><FS>345<E>
```

Source: [Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups)

More on RegEx Pattern: [Class Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

**replaceAll():**

Also `replaceAll()` does modify the String you pass as parameter but instead the function return a new one since Strings are immutable. From [String Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

```
public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
Returns:
   The resulting String
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for a capturing group:

```
str = str.replaceAll("<[A-Z](\\d)>", "<L$1>");
```

Note the assignment at the beginning. `replaceAll()` doesn't modify the string (strings are immutable); it returns a new one.

Comment: Use `group()` or `group(0)` to get the full match.